# RefCount remains unchanged after AtlUnadvise call

Tags: c#, c++, events, com

We found memory leak issue due to RefCount doesn't get decrement after AtlUnadvise().

Here is test code:

```
void CCppTesterDlg::OnBnClickedTextbtn()
{
    CComObject<CManagedGuiEventSinkImpl> *pEventSink;
    TestForm::ITestFormPtr pTestFormPtr( __uuidof(TestForm::TestForm) );

    //Attach our COM event sink to the managed dialog to listen for keyboard and mouse events
    if( CComObject<CManagedGuiEventSinkImpl>::CreateInstance(&pEventSink) == S_OK )
    {
        HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;
        DWORD   dwCookie = 0;
        CComPtr<ManagedGuiEventInterface::IManagedGuiEventSink> pSink( pEventSink );  // ref count == 1

        hr = AtlAdvise( pTestFormPtr, pSink, __uuidof(ManagedGuiEventInterface::IManagedGuiEventSink), &dwCookie );
        // ref count == 2

        //pTestFormPtr->OpenDialog();

        //Detach the event sink after the modal dialog has been closed
        hr = AtlUnadvise( pTestFormPtr, __uuidof(ManagedGuiEventInterface::IManagedGuiEventSink), dwCookie );
        // ref count == 2
    }
}
```

CManagedGuiEventSinkImpl class is used to get event from C# module, so far it works, however we found above pEventSink object doesn't get released properly.

Is there something I missed in those classes?

Any reference will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/com/vcpp/events.htm - see under the title **Event Circular Reference Issues**

Comment: Erm, how exactly do you see the reference count on the CCW of a managed interface?  That's buried deep in the CLR.

Answer (score 0):

> > how exactly do you see the reference count on the CCW of a managed interface?
> >     pEventSink is a CComObject object, so you could check ref count in watch window, it's not a managed object.

my friend just showed me that FinalRelease() will be hit after GC.Collect() gets called, so it's holding by .net GC.

thanks all.